# Trying to replace each record having a button in AngularJS with only one button for records that are selected

Tags: angularjs, button

So I'm working on an app that has a table listing records that have been added to a database. As it currently stands, line in the table has a record entry with one edit and one delete button for each record.  So as you scroll, lots of lines, lots of delete and edit and delete buttons.  I'd like to keep the table as is and get rid of the all the buttons, instead having only 2 total buttons outside of the table at the bottom of the page where you would highlight the table entry in some way and the buttons would correspond to the actions.  This is all done in the controller, but I'm reworking someone else's stuff, so it's a bit tricky.   Any suggestions? My code in the controller looks something like this:

```
$scope.edit = function(id) {


        myApp.edit($scope.svc, id)
            .then(function(data) {

                $scope.record = data;

            }, function() {
                console.log('error in removing the record : ' + id);
            });
    };

    $scope.add = function() {

        console.log($scope.record);
        myApp.add($scope.svc, $scope.record)
            .then(function(data) {

                refresh();

            }, function() {
                console.log('error in adding the record : ');
            });
    };

    $scope.update = function() {

        console.log($scope.record);
        myApp.update($scope.svc, $scope.record)
            .then(function(data) {
                refresh();
            }, function() {
                console.log('error in adding the record : ');
            });
    };      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really highlight what error / issue you were having but I'll show you how I'd implement this:

Create one global record variable in your controller.
Each time a record is clicked, set the global record variable to be the clicked record. Then on your two buttons you simply invoke the edit / delete functions which work off of the global record variable.

On your table row repeater:

```
<tr ... ng-repeat="record of records" ng-click="setActiveRecord(record)">
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.activeRecord = {}
$scope.setActiveRecord = (record) => { $scope.activeRecord = record }
$scope.add = () => { ... }
$scope.edit = (record) => { /* your edit logic using $scope.activeRecord */ }
$scope.delete = (record) => { /* your delete logic using $scope.activeRecord  */ }
```

As some basic UX you'd want to show which record is currently active, so perhaps by using `ng-class`:

```
<tr ... ng-repeat="record of records" ng-class="{ 'your-css-classname' : record.id === activeRecord.id }">
```